# How to initiate array with null objects that gets updated?

Tags: java

I have a (rather static)  class like:

```
class Test
{
    private Planet gault;
    private Planet irtok;
    private Planet ktaris;

    /* problem:
    private Planet [] planets = {
        this.gault, this.irtok, this.ktaris
    };
    */

    Test() {

    }

    public void doTest() {
        this.gault  = new Planet("Klingon", 1322);
        this.irtok  = new Planet("Ferengi", 1213);
        this.ktaris = new Planet("Ktarian", 16512);
    }
}
```

What I want (if I can) is to have an array pointing to each planet - .

```
private Planet [] planets = {
    this.gault, this.irtok, this.ktaris
};
```

So that I in `doTest()` can do something like:

```
for (Planet p: in planets)
    p.printInfo();
```

From the various ways I've tried I always end up with `p` being NULL;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your planets are null by default. You only initialize them in the `doTest()` method. But the line initializing the array of planets is executed long before: when the Test object is constructed. So at this time, all the planets are still null, since `doTest()` has not been called yet.

The array should be initialized right after the planets are. And everything should probablybe done in the constructor rather than in `doTest()`.

Comment: OK. Thought objects (might) got an address on stack or heap that was kept (and could be referenced to) - even if set before initialized.

Comment: No. Java passes references to objects by value. So assigning `gault` to `planets[0]` makes a copy of the gault reference and initializes thefirstelement to this copy. If you assign another planet to `gault` later, the array will still point to the previous planet, since it contains a copy of the reference.

Comment: Ah. OK. Thank you. That truly explains my case.

Answer (score 3):

> From the various ways I've tried I always end up with p being NULL;

This is most likely because the following fields were `null` when you copied them

```
private Planet [] planets = {
   this.gault, this.irtok, this.ktaris
};
```

I suggest making these planets `final`.

```
private final Planet gault  = new Planet("Klingon", 1322);
private final Planet irtok  = new Planet("Ferengi", 1213);
private final Planet ktaris = new Planet("Ktarian", 16512);
```

Using your debugger is a simple way to check this.

Comment: Looks promising. One problem I have (that I did not state in the Q (out of ignorance)) is that I have a throw on error on Planet(). This is perhaps bad ? (To throw on class initiator).

Comment: Wasn't aware of `jdb` (If that is what you meant by debugger). Is it much like `gdb` (if you know that one).

Comment: My guess is that Peter meant: your IDE's debugger. If you don't use an IDE yet, then start using one. And if the Planet constructor (that's how it's called and not initiator) throws an exception (that's how it's called, and not error) then, put all the code in the Test constructor, and make it throw the exception as well.

Comment: @JBNizet: No IDE allowed text editor + terminal. (I'm on vim + Linux)). School project, (you might have suspected). And yes. I added exception to the initiator – as if e.g. number is negative throw error. Have to ask my tutor if this is good/normal practice.

Comment: Since you're learning, I'll repeat. Words matter. It's called a constructor and not an initiator. And it's called an exception and not an error. And it's actually good practice to throw an exception if an illegal argument is passed. But it should be a runtime exception (specifically: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException), that thus doesn't need to be declared in the throws clause.

Comment: @JBNizet I agree, It may seem pedantic but computers are pedantic. They do what you tell them to not what you mean.

Comment: @JBNizet: Yes! Words matter. Thank you. On to the Exception you mention. I had not caught the difference between RuntimeExceptions and Exceptions. That is a huge difference. I'll read more on that. Thanks again. And thank you Peter, I took good notice of your answer as well ;)

Comment: @Sukminder If it's a school project I would still use an IDE to develop the code and transfer it to the system when it's working BTW I only use Linux+Intellij CE for development.

Answer (score 1):

Make a class `PlanetHolder` that references a Planet:

```
public class PlanetHolder {
    Planet p
}
```

And now change your code to the following:

```
class Test {
    private PlanetHolder gault = new PlanetHolder();
    private PlanetHolder irtok = new PlanetHolder();
    private PlanetHolder ktaris = new PlanetHolder();

    private PlanetHolder [] planets = {
        this.gault, this.irtok, this.ktaris
    };

    public void doTest() {
        this.gault.p  = new Planet("Klingon", 1322);
        this.irtok.p  = new Planet("Ferengi", 1213);
        this.ktaris.p = new Planet("Ktarian", 16512);
    }
}
```

Now you can iterate over the planets and print them:

```
for (PlanetHolder p : planets) {
    p.p.printInfo();
}
```